# Yii make active record apply a MySQL function when fetching fields?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I have a MySQL column that is of `timestamp` type, called `updated`. I want Yii to fetch it by default with `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(status_updated)` in the Active Record model. So that I can do this:

```
$timestamp_as_integer = MyModel::model()->findByPk(1)->updated;
```

Is this easily possible? Right now I'm parsing the `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format that MySQL returns for all date time column types to get the integer timestamp but I was curios if I can force the database to do it for me?

Comment: Why would you want that? Convert the column type to `INT` if you need only a timestamp value.

Comment: I'd prefer having the database store the value in it's native format but utilize it as integer timestamp in my application.

Comment: Then convert in your application, don't do it in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Perform the conversion in the model:

```
protected function afterFind() {
    parent::afterFind();

    $this->status_updated = strtotime($this->status_updated);
}
```

Now after you perform a 'find' on the model, the property `status_updated` will automatically have it in `int` timestamp format.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to write a getter:

```
public function getUpdatedTimestamp()
{
    return strtotime($this->updated);
}
```

The nice thing is, you can now access it as `$model->updatedTimestamp` and still have the original DB value in `$model->updated`.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, but this should work.

```
$timestamp_as_integer = MyModel::model()->findByPk(1, array(
    'select' => array(new CDbExpression('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated) as updated'))
))->updated;
```